# Defining multiline functions in .ghci file

Tags: haskell, ghci

Can you define a multi-line function in the `.ghci` file?

I've tried

```
 what :: Show a => a -> a
 what = Db.traceShowId
```

But this didn't work. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Why not just write it in a separate .hs file and have your .ghci load that?

Comment: You can also write haskell using curly braces and semicolons to fit it in a oneliner: `what :: Show a => a -> a ; what = Db.traceShowId`. You can do case statements:  `case x of {1 -> "one"; 2 -> "two"; _ -> "I don't know" }`, instance definitions `instance Num a => Num (X a) { (+) => liftA2 (+); (*) = liftA2 (*); {- ... -} }`, and any other construct.

Comment: @Cubic That worked great, I created a `.ghci.hs` file and loaded it in `.ghci` with `:load ~/.ghci.hs`

Comment: @Cubic You should perhaps create an answer about that since current answer is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The .ghci file is not the proper place for such definitions.

Still, if you really must, you can use

```
:{
line1
line2
...
:}
```

otherwise, you can try to put the whole definition in one line

```
line1 ; line2 ; ...
```

Comment: it's worth noting that that a single multiline statement can contain either multiple definitions (like `newtype Unit = Unit ()` or a single expression (like `1 + 2`).

Comment: @hgiesel Ah, interesting. I assumed it worked. Try the alternative I added in my edit.

Comment: @hgiesel Both methods suggested here do work for me. Can you edit your question to include the exact thing you tried? Maybe include your GHC version, as well.